# twitter4J access token and access secret

Tags: twitter4j

I want to analyse a twitter page.  when i was doing research, i found something about access token and access secret.  i am very confused about it.  If someone can give an explanation, that would be very helpful. By the way , what i try to do here is to get the tweet text from a twitter account( not my personal one but a public one). Any suggestions?

below is my code

```
import twitter4j.Paging; 
import twitter4j.ResponseList;
import twitter4j.Status;
import twitter4j.Twitter;
import twitter4j.auth.AccessToken;
import twitter4j.TwitterFactory;
public class GetUserStatus{
 public static void main( String[]args){
  Twitter twitter= new TwitterFactory().getInstance();
  // my application consumer and auth Access Token
  twitter.setOAuthConsumer("consumerkey","consumer secret");
  twitter.setOAuthAccessToken(new AccessToken("accesstoken","access secret"));

  try{
   ResponseList<Status>a =twitter.getUserTimeline(new Paging(1,5));
   for (Status b:a){
    System.out.println(b.getText());
   }

  }catch(Exception e){
 }
}
}
```

Comment: did you register your app with twitter?

Comment: i only need to extract the tweet. honestly i don't have an app. so under this situation what should i do?

Comment: sign up with your app so that you access their service using twitter4J - registering the app will result in their service generating token for you.

Answer (score 0):

To receive tweets, perform searches, or do any other task on Twitter API, you need to first register an app. It's free and easy.

Steps:

- Go to https://apps.twitter.com/ and after signing into Twitter click on "create a new app"
- Fill in the details for your new app(You are free to choose any name, give a brief description)
- After creation, you'll see your application, in it click on "keys and tokens" tab and copy your consumer key, consumer secret, access token and access secret
- Now, as per instructions given [here](http://twitter4j.org/en/configuration.html) setup your configuration
- Done, you can now perform searches on Twitter API and do other stuff also.

(I suppose all you want is receive tweets)